# Vue.js how to get data in controller from parent, calculate new variables and show them reactively

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

I have two components. `CreditForm.vue` and `InformationBlock.vue`

```html
<template>
    <form class="parent">
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="property_value">property_value</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="property_value" v-model.number="property_value">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="initial_fee">initial_fee</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="initial_fee" v-model.number="initial_fee">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="credit_term">credit_term</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="credit_term" v-model.number="credit_term">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="interest_rate">interest_rate</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="interest_rate" v-model.number="interest_rate">
            </div>
            <div class="d-inline-flex">
                <b-button @click="save">Save</b-button>
                <b-button @click="clear">Clear</b-button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <information-block :property_value="property_value"
                           :initial_fee="initial_fee"
                           :credit_term="credit_term"
                           :interest_rate="interest_rate"/>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    import InformationBlock from "@/components/InformationBlock";

    export default {
        name: "CreditForm",
        components: {InformationBlock},
        data() {
            return {
                property_value: 0,
                initial_fee: 0,
                credit_term: 0,
                interest_rate: 0
            }
        },
        methods: {
            save: function () {

            },
            clear: function () {
                this.property_value = 0
                this.initial_fee = 0
                this.credit_term = 0
                this.interest_rate = 0
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And second one.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        {{property_value}}
        {{initial_fee}}
        {{credit_term}}
        {{interest_rate}}
        <table class="inner table table-borderless">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <h5>month_pay</h5>
                        <h1>{{month_pay}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <h5>income</h5>
                        <h1>{{income}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <h5>overpayment</h5>
                        <h1>{{overpayment}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <h5>loan_body</h5>
                        <h1>{{loan_body}}</h1>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "InformationBlock",
        props: {
            property_value: {
                required: true,
            },
            initial_fee: {
                required: true,
            },
            credit_term: {
                required: true,
            },
            interest_rate: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        data: function () {
            let loan_body = this.property_value-this.initial_fee
            let t = this.interest_rate/1200
            let month_pay = Math.round(loan_body*(t + t/(Math.pow((1+t), this.credit_term*12)-1)))
            let income = Math.round(5 * month_pay/3)
            let overpayment = Math.round(month_pay*this.credit_term*12-this.property_value+this.initial_fee)
            return {
                loan_body,
                income,
                overpayment,
                month_pay
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

In child component I need to get 4 variables from parent, do some math and show new variables reactively, on change of every input. So this should be simple but I'm doing something wrong, can you help me?

Comment: `computed` property is what you are looking for. Docs for Vue are very good, take a look https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `data` properties into [`computed` properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties), which are automatically updated when any of its dependencies (the incoming `props` in this case) change:

```js
// InformationBlock.vue
export default {
    props: {/*...*/},

    // data: function () {
    //     let loan_body = this.property_value-this.initial_fee
    //     let t = this.interest_rate/1200
    //     let month_pay = Math.round(loan_body*(t + t/(Math.pow((1+t), this.credit_term*12)-1)))
    //     let income = Math.round(5 * month_pay/3)
    //     let overpayment = Math.round(month_pay*this.credit_term*12-this.property_value+this.initial_fee)
    //     return {
    //         loan_body,
    //         income,
    //         overpayment,
    //         month_pay
    //     }
    // },

    computed: {
        load_body() {
            return this.property_value - this.initial_fee
        },
        income() {
            return Math.round(5 * this.month_pay/3)
        },
        overpayment() {
            return Math.round(this.month_pay * this.credit_term * 12 - this.property_value + this.initial_fee)
        },
        month_pay() {
            let t = this.interest_rate/1200
            return Math.round(this.loan_body*(t + t/(Math.pow((1+t), this.credit_term*12)-1)))
        }
    }
}
```